# Realtek RTL8188EE Wi-Fi unstable connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, realtek, ubuntu-netbook, realtek-wireless

I tried everything, I installed an alternative driver rtlwifi_new but nothing ...
I tried to compile the drivers downloaded from the realtek and I received errors in compilation ...
The connection is not constant, when I connect to wifi university is very slow, no more than 0.10 mb / s download ...
It is unusable, while at home is fine.
I exclude that the network is a problem because other people with Ubuntu does everything correctly.
I have 3.19.0-33-generic x86_64 as kernel and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

iI hope we can find a solution
Thanks a lot

Comment: nobody help me?

Comment: finding the same issue here